# How can I make my eclipse java project a desktop app and installable without eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, exe

I have a program that I wrote in eclipse that uses selenium, other lib files, and a config.properties that you have to import.

How can I turn this program into a double-clickable exe/.jar file on a desktop that can be usable without eclipse?

I want to send my program to a friend that doesn't have eclipse but I just can't figure out how to do it. I originally thought I was supposed to export my project in eclipse as a runnable jar file but that didn't work when I sent it to my friend. What else can I do?

Comment: Does your friend have the appropriate Java Runtime Environment installed? Because they would need that to run a .jar file. What do you mean by "didn't work"? What error does trying to run it give?

Comment: A runnable jar is correct. Are you including the other necessary library/jar files with your own jar? Is your manifest correct, especially its class-path statement?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is not only to make the program runnable (as lobster1234 proposed) but to make it actually installable. We have recently used IzPack[http://izpack.org/](http://izpack.org/). It actually looks nice. There are also some decent tutorials on the details here
http://www.softwarepassion.com/deploy-your-java-application-with-izpack-installer/

Comment: from eclipse, right click on project -> export -> choose runnable jar, and choose the main class and location, thats it, but there are only 40% of chance of getting a good runnable jar, because there are many more conditions that people mess inside that, success to export the jar but it didn't run, but this is a simple procedure to make it, another is with maven and gradle, choice is yours, good luck for runnable jar....